# Регулярные выражения для поиска наименования месяца в тексте

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь найти те предложения, в которых содержится название месяца как даты, которая может быть записано по-разному, например  “*апр*”, “*апрель*(и все его склонения)”, “*apr*”, “*april*” и “*04*” (предложение в нижнем регистре). При этом в идеале нужно, чтобы предыдущий и последующий символ были только либо пробелом “ ”, либо точкой “.”, либо одинарной кавычкой “'”, либо их вообще не было. Нужно просто найти первое вхождение, а где оно, есть ли дальше другие - неважно.

Написал такое выражение:
`re.match(r'.*?(апр(?:ель|еля|елю|елем|еле)|apr(?:il)|04(?:\W)?)', sentence)`, но оно покрывает не все описанные выше случаи - к примеру, не срабатывает на "*В апр 2020 задолженность*" и ложно срабатывает на “*У нашей заправки задолженность*”, “*апрельская задолженность*” и на “*044*”.

Подскажите, как должно выглядеть правильное выражение, заранее спасибо)

Comment: `re.search(r'\b(апрел(?:[ьяюе]|ем)|apr(?:il)?|04)\b', sentence)`?

Comment: благодарю, но это выражение не покрывает случаи с “апр”, “апр.”, “апр ” и “апр'”

Comment: Тогда `re.search(r'\b(апр(?:ел(?:[ьяюе]|ем)?)?|apr(?:il)?|04)\b', sentence)`

Comment: Отлично, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```py
re.search(r'\b(апр(?:ел(?:[ьяюе]|ем)?)?|apr(?:il)?|04)\b', sentence)
```

**Подробности**

- `\b` - граница слова
- `(` - начало подмаски №1

  - `апр` - строка `апр`
  - `(?:ел(?:[ьяюе]|ем)?)?` - `ел`, после которого следует один или ноль (т.е. опционально) `ь`, `я`, `ю`, `е` или `ем`
- `|` - или

  - `apr` - строка `apr`
  - `(?:il)?` - необязательная последовательности символов `il`
- `|` - или

  - `04` - `04`
- `)` - конец подмаски
- `\b` - граница слова